# Grunt isn't loading

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Please bear with me because I am new to node and grunt.

When I run Grunt using:

```
Wine-MacBook-JT:sass-test jthomas$ grunt
```

I get the following error:

**Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR**

> > Error: Unable to parse "package.json" file (Unexpected token } in JSON at position 248).
> >     Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Not sure what the issue is. My JSON Code is:

```
{
  "name": "sass-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple test project for Grunt and Sass",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch@1.0.0"
  }
}
```

My Directory structure is set up as

```
||sass-test
   ||.sass-cache
   ||.node-modules
   SCSS
     ||_main.scss
     ||_mixins.scss
     ||_style.scss

Gruntfile.js
package.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"grunt-contrib-watch@1.0.0"` line in your `package.json` is not valid json.

I would delete that line, and just use `npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-watch` to re-add it to the package.json. Otherwise, just modify it by hand to something like:

```
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0"
```

And make sure you `npm install` again, if you modify the `package.json` by hand, since there's a good chance that package is not actually installed.

Here's the full fixed `package.json` blob:

```
{
  "name": "sass-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple test project for Grunt and Sass",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line "grunt-contrib-watch@1.0.0" for "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0"